# 'Profile' object is not iterable

Tags: html, django, django-views

views.py.

```
@login_required
def friends_profile(request):
f_profiles = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
return render(request, 'mains/friends_profile.html', {'f_profiles':f_profiles} )
```

urls.py

```
path('friends_profile/', views.friends_profile, name='friends_profile'),
```

template = friends_profile.html

```
{% extends "mains/base.html" %}

{% block content %}



  {% for friends in f_profiles %}
    {{ friends.full_name }}
  {% empty %}
    <li>NO DATA</li>
  {% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='friends',blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=60,default='')
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def get_friends(self):
    return self.friends.all()

def get_friends_no(self):
    return self.friends.all().count()

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username}'

STATUS_CHOICES = ( 
    ('send', 'send'),
    ('accepted','accepted'),
)

class Relationship(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='receiver')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.sender}-{self.receiver}-{self.status}"
```

'Profile' object is not iterable. This is raising when i open this template( friends_profiles.html ). Please... Help me in this ERROR. What am i missing in this ?

I will really appreciate your HELP.

Answer (score -1):

You are only passing a single object `f_profiles` in the context to the template, but are trying to iterate over an iterable by doing `{% for friends in f_profiles %}`.

`f_profiles = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)` this will only give you one object which is the profile of the `request.user`. You are not getting friends of the user with this line of code.

Also, it maybe better to use
`f_profiles = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)`

Try to replace this code in the templates:

```
{% for friends in f_profiles %}
    {{ friends.full_name }}
```

with

```
{% for friend in f_profiles.friends.all %}
     {{ friend.full_name}}
```

or

```
{% for friend in f_profiles.get_friends %}
    {{ friend.full_name }}
```